How can i make nested menu by using tabs on wordpress?
i am trying to make a menu using two nested elementor tabs i added event listener to the parent tab to show the content on hover but it doesnt work
<script>
    let parent = document.getElementById('parent');
   
    parent.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
       document.getElementById('content').visibility = 'visible'  ;
    });
</script>

the content has #content{  visibility: hidden;} under custom css section

Can you give the generated html for this tabs in your question.
